# clip in CSS keep the image size to original

Tags: html, css

I am using this css code to show portion of a large image

```
img.ac{
 position: absolute;
clip: rect(0px,72px,97px,0px);
}
```

My original image size is 949 px to 349px. When I clip the image, the size of image remains the same. How can I set the size of the image equal to the clipped image size?

I would like also to use in a layout all the clipped images.

After Update

My current code is :

```
.a{
   width:72px;
   height:97px;
   overflow:hidden;
  }

 img.ca{
 position: absolute;
clip: rect(0px,72px,97px,0px);  
 }
```

Please refer : http://jsfiddle.net/3a3sj4r1/

**Now the problem is that there is unwanted space between two images as appear in example. How can i avoid it?**

Comment: css clip is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip), is there a reason you must use it?

Comment: I don't understand why you would clip an image and then adjust it to be the size of the clipping mask? Why don't you just set the width and be done with it?

Comment: @deolectrix I want to display part of image. With clip i am displaying that part. But when part of image is displayed it is acquiring space in HTML for whole image. Instead of that i want it to acquire space that small image needs.

Comment: @vishalpatel you could also do it as background, demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d3uLtvrv/

Comment: Just added a new demo with no spaces between each image. check my update. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using clip which will still keep the image size (it will just hide the part clipped) you can wrap the image in a container with `overflow:hidden;` without setting any CSS property to the image.
Otherwise the image will just scale keeping the ratio.

```
.clip{
    width:72px;
    height:97px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/cL5tc37x/3/

If you add another image, you will see that there is no space taken by the clipped image.

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/cL5tc37x/5/

**UPDATE to remove spaces**

If you need to remove the space from each image just add `float:left;`

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/cL5tc37x/7/

Applying it to your code you could also do:

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/3a3sj4r1/2/

Comment: This is not helping me. Try to hover over img tag in console in your demo. You will see that img tag is taking size of original image in HTML. What i want is to cliped image will take only clipped size.

Comment: You don't need to inspect the img element but the its container to see the width and the image is hidden cause it overflows. Look here
http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/cL5tc37x/4/

Comment: But this affect how other things display on html page.

Comment: I want to display other image/content at that part.

Comment: You can still use the space which is hidden by overflow:hidden; on the side of the first img.

Comment: This one worked. Problem was i was applying overflow in image tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75608/discussion-between-vishal-patel-and-alex-incarnati).

Comment: Please refer my example: http://jsfiddle.net/3a3sj4r1/1/ Its not working with my code.